# how to monitor bandwidth consumption of a virtual machine

Tags: virtualization, bandwidth-measuring

I have a windows server and four virtual machines running on it. Different applications are running on each of those virtual machines. So without logging into each of the virtual machines separately i'd like to know how can i monitor and calculate the bandwidth consumption for each of these virtual machines from the host itself.

Is there a windows command or a script which can provide me this data ?

Also is it possible to integrate this data with some program like cacti ?

since all services are currently running on a single system(localhost) for testing purposes so i've added below lines to gmond conf file to setup gmond as receiver

```
globals {
  daemonize = yes
  setuid = yes
  user = ganglia
  debug_level = 0
  max_udp_msg_len = 1472
  mute = no
  deaf = no
  allow_extra_data = yes
  host_dmax = 0 /*secs */
  cleanup_threshold = 300 /*secs */
  gexec = no
  send_metadata_interval = 0 /*secs */
}

cluster {
  name = "laptop"
  owner = "unspecified"
  latlong = "unspecified"
  url = "unspecified"
}

udp_recv_channel {
  port = 6343
}
```

Also my hsflowd configuration is as follows:-

```
sflow{
  DNSSD = off
  polling = 10
  sampling = 400
  collector{
   ip = 127.0.0.1
   udpport = 6343
  }
}
```

My Gmetad configuration is as follows:-

```
data_source "laptop" 127.0.0.1
case_sensitive_hostnames 1
```

Thanks,
Avdhesh

Answer (score 0):

I've recently setup sflow/ganglia to do this in my environment.

[image]

http://blog.sflow.com/2010/10/ganglia.html

Comment: It helps if you explain your answer on-site

Comment: I've managed to install sflow, gmond and gmetad on my laptop (centos 6.5) and configure properly. I'm able to see the gmond data in the ganglia-web interface but i'm unable to see anything related to sflow. Where and how is the sflow data rendered on ganglia interface ?

Comment: I updated the link above to a newer post.

Comment: I'm assuming you've set up an sflow "receiver". You need to setup the sflow "senders".

Comment: I've updated my question with gmond and hsflowd configuration. I assume gmond is the receiver here and hsflowd the sender.

Comment: The link is corrupted!

Comment: Link works, just tried